# iis express unable to access the iis metabase error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, iis-express, iis-metabase

I'm developing an asp.net mvc application using Visual Studio 2015 community. When i tried to configure the application to use the iis express server, it throw the following error :

**Unable to access the IIS metabase. You do not have sufficient privilege to access IIS web sites on your machine.**

I'v tried all the proposed solutions below but without any success :

1. Check the following registery key : **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders\Personal**, and ensure that it point to a valid directory(Actually %USERPROFILE%\Documents),
2. Taking ownership of  %systemroot%\inetsrv\config directory,
3. Run Visual Studio 2015 as administrator,
4. Remove/Install the IISExpress (i have tried all versions :10,8 and 7.5).

Any help about this issues would be very appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? You might uninstall and reinstall IIS Express to see if the error remains.

Comment: Thanks  Lex Li for your reply. I updated my question to give all the proposed solutions that i'v tried.

Comment: 1) VS uses `Microsoft.Web.Administration` in .NET 4.0 GAC to manipulate IIS Express, so you need to check if that assembly is registered properly. 2) VS2015 web projects use applicationHost.config file in `.vs` hidden folder for each solutions, so you might also check if that file exists and is not corrupt.